# Вопрос по подписчикам в Magento

Tags: cms, magento

как в настройках не активных подписчиков (Not Activated) перевести в статус Subscribed, то есть в подписавшихся на новости. я думаю,что есть способ без перехода по ссылке активации подписки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в настройках `system(система)->configuration(конфигурация)->клиеты(customers)->newslatter(рассылка)->Параметры подписки(params newslater)->Необходимо подтвержение(requir apruve)` ставите его в значение `нет(no)` английская локализация может несовпадать так как по памяти писал.

для активации всех не активированных пишем shell

```
$newsletterCollection = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->getCollection();
// фильтруем коллекцию по тем чьи email не подтвержденны
$newsletterCollection->addFieldToFilter('status',2);

foreach($newsletterCollection->load() as $_newsletter) {
    $_newsletter->setStatus(1); // ставим статус подтверждён
    $_newsletter->save(); // сохраняем подписчика
    echo $_newsletter->getEmail().'[ok]'.PHP_EOL; // добавляем вывод
}
```

как написать shell? в папке shell создаёте файлик `myshell.php`

с содержимом

```
require_once 'abstract.php';

class My_Shell_MyShell extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
     public function run() 
     {
           if ($this->getArg('run')) {
              $this->setStatus();
           }
     }

     public function setStatus() 
     {
         // тут код который делает автоматическую подписку
         // представлен выше
     }
}

$shell = new My_Shell_MyShell();
$shell->run();
```

запуск скрипта

> 1. логинимся по ssh к серверу
> 2. переходим в папку shell `cd /path/to/mage/shell`
> 3. запускаем скрипт командой `php -f myshell.php -- run`

Comment: спасибо)это да, я и так No поставил, но было время, когда там Yes было и вот в это время подписались люди  и вот их бы хотелось активировать для рассылок, а как ... не могу найти решение

Comment: щас отредактирую ответ